# Amazon Elasticsearch - Not able to access Kibana

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I have launched Elasticsearch in a Public Subnet, still, I am not able to access the Kibana console from my browser. I am not able to understand the issue, I have configured the Security Group correctly.
Please refer the image below for my setup :

[image]

What other setting needs to be made to access Elasticsearch over the internet in a VPC.

Comment: did you tried the suggested answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you place your Elastic Search Cluster inside a VPC, whether inside a public or private subnet, the Kibana URL which is generated is internal to the VPC. Which means you cannot access it outside the VPC. You can access it through an EC2 instance inside the VPC i.e. you will have to create a windows EC2 instance inside the same VPC as Kibana and then you will be able to access the Kibana dashboard through the browser of that instance.

Comment: I believe this answer is right, for more information you can check https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kibana-outside-vpc-nginx-elasticsearch/. You don't need to specifically use a windows machine for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update access policy of the cluster -> ELK -> domain -> Modify access policy

[image]

Select a template from the drop-down or update it manually and your IP

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:**youraccountnumber***:domain/dmainname/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "202.your_public_ip_adress/32"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or further you can share the browser output which should be something like the user is allowed?

How u create your ELK cluster there is two option?

[image]

Comment: I am facing error : `CreateElasticsearchDomain: {"message":"You can’t attach an IP-based policy to a domain that has a VPC endpoint. Instead, use a security group to control IP-based access."}`

Comment: okay, so it means you are using SG group-based cluster,  can you show your SG group or did you add public IP properly?  enable 443 port from SG?

Comment: check your ELK subnet properly associated with VPC?

Comment: I have verified even for SG you stil need to updated access policy is that the case?